# How to allocate more CPU and RAM to SUMO (Simulation of Urban Mobility)

Tags: sumo

I have downloaded and unzipped sumo-win64-0.32.0 and running sumo.exe this on a powerful machine (64GB ram, Xeon CPU E5-1650 v4 3.6GHz) for about 140k trips,   108k edges, and 25k vehicles types which are departed in the first 30 min of simulation. I have noticed that my CPU is utilized only 30% and Memory only 38%, Is there any way to increase the speed by forcing sumo to use more CPU and ram, or possibly run in parallel? From ["Can SUMO be run in parallel (on multiple cores or computers)?](http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/FAQ#Can_SUMO_be_run_in_parallel_.28on_multiple_cores_or_computers.29.3F)
The simulation itself always runs on a single core."

it appears that parallel processing is not possible t, but what about dedicating more CPU and ram?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows usually shows the CPU utilization such that 100% means all cores are used, so 30% is probably already more than one core and there is no way of increasing that with a single threaded application as sumo. Also if your scenario fits within RAM completely there is no point of increasing that. You might want to try one of the several parallelization approaches SUMO has but none of them got further than some toy examples (and none is in the official distribution) and the speed improvements are sometimes only marginal. Probably the best you can do is to do some profiling and find the performance bottlenecks and/or send your results to the developers.